# systemd-modules-load print errors when loading builtin kernel modules

Tags: arch-linux, kernel-modules

I'm running Arch Linux, it uses `systemd-modules-load` to load modules configured in /etc/rc.conf, but since I use a custom kernel and lts kernel, I had to put all possible modules in that config file (in custom kernel most of those are builtin)

During boot I could see errors from `systemd-modules-load`, like `XX is not implemented` or so , for those builtin module.

Is that a bug ? (modprobe builtin_module doesn't print error)